# Setting text color of TextView in GTK#

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, gtk#

I'm working on highlighting for a TextView component of my application, and I can't seem to find the API references on how to accomplish this.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how I can accomplish this, or possibly towards the documentation that says how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply TextTags to ranges of text in the TextBuffer.  Create the tags on the buffer's TextTagTable and then Apply then to a range using TextIters to specify the start and end point for the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [GtkSourceView](http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceview/)?